# Control LookupEdit no muestra el display member

Tags: c#, devexpress

No consigo que un control `LookUpEdit` me muestre el display `member`.

Tengo un formulario con controles `textbox` y un `lookupedit`, todo ello vinculado a un `gridcontrol`. A medida que me desplazo por el grid, los controles se actualizan con los valores del grid, pero el display member del `lookupedit` no hay manera, se muestra vacío. El grid tiene un campo `RepresentanteID` de una tabla de Proveedores y pretendo que el `lookupedit` (tabla Representantes) muestre el nombre del representante enlazado. Lo cierto es que cuando cae sobre un proveedor que tiene representante, el lookup se muestra en blanco, pero si el proveedor no tiene representante el display member muestra `[vacío]`. Creo que lo tengo correctamente configurado, tanto el `lookupedit` como las columnas del grid (donde incluyo el campo `RepresentanteID` de la tabla proveedores -oculto-).

```
txtTelefono2.Text = gridView1.GetFocusedRowCellValue("Telefono2").ToString();
....
lookRepresentante.EditValue = lookRepresentante.Properties.GetDisplayValueByKeyValue(gridView1.GetFocusedRowCellValue("RepresentanteID").ToString());
```

Alguna idea? muchas gracias por adelantado.

[image: configuración del lookupedit]
[image: configuración columnas grid]

Answer (score 0):

te recomendaria usaras el textedit, ya que el lookupedit muestra una pequena grid la cual lo mejor seria llenarla desde una datatable, es mejor una textedit, quedaria de la siguiente forma textedit.text = gridView1.GetFocusedRowCellValue("encabezado columna").ToString()) asi cada vez que le des click a una row al grid se llenara automatico con el campo seleccionado de la fila.

Comment: Gracias por tu comentario. Lo resolví  con: RepresentanteIDLookUpEdit.EditValue = gridViewProveedores.GetFocusedRowCellValue("RepresentanteID").ToString();